# Node stream catch Promise's error?

Tags: node.js, promise, stream

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => someReadStream
    .pipe(decoder)
    .on('data', data => somePromise(data))
    .on('end', () => resolve(true))
    .on('error', e => reject(e)));
```

This stream can't catch the error that thrown by somePromise.
How to catch the a Promise's error in a stream?

Also is there any way to make the stream return the result by the 'somePromise'?

Comment: Do you realize that the `data` event can be called multiple times?  If so, what do you want to return when `somePromise(data)` is called multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch somePromise like:

```
.on('data', data => somePromise(data).catch(e => reject(e)))
```

If you want to return somePromise result:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let results = [];
    someReadStream
        .pipe(decoder)
        .on('data', data => results.push(somePromise(data)))
        .on('end', () => resolve(Promise.all(results).catch(e => reject(e))))
        .on('error', e => reject(e)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The stream will not catch the error - so either you accumulate, like Andriy2 suggested (but keep in mind that you may run into memory consumption issues if you run through big ammounts of data) or you use the [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) framework like this:

```
const {DataStream} = require("scramjet");
return someReadStream
        .pipe(decoder)
        .pipe(new DataStream())
        .consume((data) => somePromise(data))
);
```

Scramjet is pretty lightweight so you'll add just 3 dependent modules in total.

`DataStream.prototype.consume` returns a Promise which makes your code even easier. :)

**-- EDIT --**

In a recent version a `catch` method was introduced so you can even handle the error to your liking - even dismiss (by resolving the `catch` block):

```
dataStream
    .catch(err => {
         if (!(err instanceOf DismissableError))
             throw err;
         logger.error("A dismissable error occured", err);
    });
```